# How can I use UTF-8 on the cmdlet New-Mailbox?

Tags: powershell, utf-8, office365, exchange-server

We are running a script to create "equipment" and "room" resources in ExchangeOnline and everything works as intended except that it will not accept UTF-8 for the cmdlet 'New-Mailbox'.

Office365 accepts our fancy Swedish characters ÅÄÖ on the resources if you manually create them via the UI but I cannot make it happen through the script.

I tried changing the default encoding for PS but that only applies to cmdlets that can accept the -Encoding argument which it doesn't.

```
$extraParams = @{ $Type = $true }
New-Mailbox -Name "$($Resource)" @extraParams
```

When using ÅÄÖ for the script we are greeted with: "String syntax failed validation"

Comment: where does the `$Resource` come from? Direct input or from a file, list, csv...

Comment: Do hard-coded values work?

Comment: $Resource variable in a Read-Host command when starting the script, so direct input.
Hard-coded values recieve the same error if foreign characters are included.

Comment: Did you save the script itself in `UTF-8 with BOM` ?

Comment: Is BOM UTF-8 for the script not the same as setting UTF-8 as PSDefault? As in only affecting cmdlets that can accept the -Encoding argument or have I misunderstood that?